# $V_{\lambda}$ as a $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ -module

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $V_{\lambda} = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} \mathbb{C}v_i$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. This is a representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ according to the following action:

$$hv_{i} = (\lambda - 2i)v_{i}, \qquad fv_{i}= v_{i+1}, \qquad ev_{i} = i(\lambda - i +1)v_{i -1}.$$

I want to find all values of $\lambda$ for which $V_{\lambda}$ is irreducible and all the submodules of $V_{\lambda}$, for the values of $\lambda$ for which $V_{\lambda}$ is not irreducible.

So far, I have only noticed that a single subspace $\mathbb{C}v_{i}$ cannot be a submodule of $V_{\lambda}$, since it is not stable under the action. So, if $W$ is a submodule of $V_{\lambda}$, then $W = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} W \cap \mathbb{C}v_i $. However, I can’t seem to understand how the choice of $\lambda$ can determine irreducibility of $V_{\lambda}$. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\lambda\in\Bbb N$, then $ev_{\lambda+1}=0$ and $\bigoplus_{i=\lambda+1}^{\infty}\Bbb Cv_{i}$ is a subrepresentation.

Comment: So for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} - \mathbb{N}$, $V_{\lambda}$ is irreducibile?

Comment: Well… yes, but what I did proves that if $\lambda\in\Bbb N$, then $V_\lambda$ is reducible.

Comment: Yes, of course. But how do you prove that for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} - \mathbb{N}$ $V_{\lambda}$ is irreducible?

Comment: If $\lambda\notin\Bbb N$ and if $W$ is a submodule, take $w\in W$. Then $w=\alpha_0v_0+\alpha_1v_1+\cdots+\alpha_kv_k$, with $\alpha_k\ne0$. But then $e_i^{\,k}w=\omega v_0$ for some $\omega\ne0$. So, $v_0\in W$ and therefore $W=V_\lambda$.

Comment: $W$ is not necessarily finite dimensional: how do you know that $w$ is a finite combination of $v_i$? Also, who is $e_{i}^{k}$?

Comment: Of course that $W$ doesn't have to be finite-dimensional! So what? The set $\{e_i\mid i\in\Bbb N\}$ is a basis of $V_\lambda$ and therefore each element of $V_\lambda$ is a linear combination of a *finite* number of $e_i$'s.

Comment: Ok, I am just trying to understand what's going on :) thanks though